# Сравнение даты с выбранном диапазоном и заполнение таблицы

Tags: java, android, дата

Стоит такая задача. Получаю Json из базы данных SQL:

```
  {"id":"1","date":"2015-03-11 10:16:10"}
```

Из него получаю стринг в формате:

```
  yyyy-mm-dd: String date = 2015-03-11.
```

В приложении на андроид я имею два `EditText` (один для ввода даты "С", а другой для ввода даты "По", в формате dd.mm.yyy) , где мне необходимо мою `date` сравнить с введенным пользователем интервалом дат. Если совпадает, то нужно сделать таблицу, отфильтрованную по месяцам (для этого делаю счетчик `int count++`):

```
  Месяц      Число участников   
  Январь          ... (count)
  Февраль         ... 
  Март            ... 
  ...
```

Сравнение думаю можно сделать так:

```
boolean isWithinRange(Date testDate) {
return testDate.after(startDate) && testDate.before(endDate);
}
```

Как подсчитать количество участников, которое соответствует месяцу январь, февраль и т.д. и как лучше сделать такую таблицу на андроид?